# Forbidden 403: Able to access localhost but unable to access folders within

Tags: php, apache2, localhost, osx-elcapitan

I am able to access localhost and a folder inside it (http://localhost/ariaconfig/) but am unable to go further.

I am trying to access /Library/WebServer/Documents/ariaconfig/rest
I have given access permission of read and write and also made the folder shared (using mac).

In my httpd.conf :
have altered these lines but of no use.

```
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    Order deny,allow
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In my httpd-vhosts.conf have added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-error_log"   
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

In error_log getting error as:

```
Cannot serve directory /Library/Webserver/Documents/ariaconfig/rest/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.html,index.php,index.html,index.php) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a spelling mistake in your httpd-vhosts.conf

DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents

this should be `Webserver` instead of `WebServer` S should be small as per your rules

If thats not the case , please check index.html or index.php persist in your Document Root , If not please create it with some dummy html file . That would be the starting point for any web browser .

[Check out this wiki article on webserver directory index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webserver_directory_index)

Comment: I think i made a mistake while copying it over here. I checked the spelling and still the error (Forbidden) persists.

Comment: I made an index.html under /Library/WebServer/Documents. Also, index.html is already present under /Library/WebServer/Documents/ariaconfig but still no use :(

Comment: can you try different Options i Directory . like Options None and see .

Comment: I added Options +Indexes in httpd.conf and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added Options +Indexes in httpd.conf.